# ASP.NET Core web application - display database data C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to display data from a SQL Server database. I've been struggling with it for a whole day now and still can't find any working solution or tutorial.

What I want to do - make a simple "database browser". The best thing that worked so far was this tutorial https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/entity-framework-database-first-in-asp-net-core2/

But I have only one table to display and I don't know how to write this part of code:

```
 public IActionResult Index()  
 {  
     var _emplst = _dbContext.tblEmployees
                             .Join(_dbContext.tblSkills, e => e.SkillID, s => s.SkillID,  
                                   (e, s) => new EmployeeViewModel  
                                                 { EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID, EmployeeName = e.EmployeeName,  
                                                   PhoneNumber = e.PhoneNumber, Skill = s.Title,  
                                                   YearsExperience = e.YearsExperience }).ToList();  

     IList<EmployeeViewModel> emplst  = _emplst;  
     return View(emplst);  
}
```

for just one table (without any join). Everything I try ends up with an error that I cannot convert `tblEmployees` to `EmployeeViewModel`.

Could someone possibly help me? Or suggest any other solution, that might work? I really just want to drag a data from a table and display it on a web page.

EDIT:
ComponentContext.cs:

```
public class ComponentsContext:DbContext
    {
        public ComponentsContext(DbContextOptions<ComponentsContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<tblComponents> tblComponent { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe for such a "generic" database browser, Entity Framework might not be the best choice. Maybe you need to go back to "old-school" low-level ADO.NET to handle such a scenario ...

Answer (score 1):

Your `_emplst` list is of a different type (class) than the type (class) `EmployeeViewModel`.

So you need to go through you list `_emplst` and transfer the values needed in `EmployeeViewModel`.

This can be something like this:

```
     public IActionResult Index()  
 {  
            var _emplst = _dbContext.tblEmployees.  
                            Join(_dbContext.tblSkills, e => e.SkillID, s => s.SkillID,  
                            (e, s) => new EmployeeViewModel  
                            { EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID, EmployeeName = e.EmployeeName,  
                                PhoneNumber = e.PhoneNumber, Skill = s.Title,  
                                YearsExperience = e.YearsExperience }).ToList();  
            var emplst  = _emplst.Select( e=> new EmployeeViewModel {
               .. i dont known the properties ..
               A = e.A,
               B = e.B,
               ... .. 
            }).ToList();  
            return View(emplst);  
  }
```

As answer to your comment below on the `tlbComponent`, try this:

```
var _cmplist = _dbContext.tblComponent.ToList().Select(e => new ComponentsViewModel { ID = e.ID, Name = e.Name, } ).ToList();
IList<ComponentsViewModel> cmplist = _cmplist;
return View(cmplist);
```

i have change `_dbContext.tblComponent.Select(...` to `_dbContext.tblComponent.ToList().Select(...`.

Comment: I tried following: var _cmplist = _dbContext.tblComponent.Select(e => new ComponentsViewModel {
                ID = e.ID,
                Name = e.Name,
            }
               )
            .ToList();
        IList<ComponentsViewModel> cmplist = _cmplist;
            return View(cmplist);  but it ends up with "invalid object name (tblComponent)"

Comment: It says that you dont have a `DbSet<TblComponent> tblComponent {get;set;}` on the type of `_dbContext`. Show the type of `_dbContext` in you question, then we can help you.

Comment: public class ComponentsContext:DbContext
    {
        public ComponentsContext(DbContextOptions<ComponentsContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<tblComponents> tblComponent { get; set; }
      
    }
}      Thank you for replying :)

Comment: Update your question with the `ComponentsContext` class, it is more readable ;)